# How can I improve this Python 3 code that alternates iterators?

Tags: python, refactoring

I recently wrote this Python 3 code that is supposed to alternate among all iterables given to it. That is, if the function is given as arguments `(first, second, third)` then it yields `first[0], second[0], third[0], first[1], ...`. If `second` runs out before the others, then it is skipped: `second[15], third[16], first[16], third[16], ...` until all iterables are exhausted.

Here it is. It is functional, but it doesn't look very "pythonic". I especially don't like having to keep an array of flags that tell me if the generators are empty.

```
def zipper(*many):
    iterators = [iter(x) for x in many]
    iHasItems = [True]*len(iterators)
    while any(iHasItems):
        for n, iterator in enumerate(iterators):
            if iHasItems[n]:
                try:
                    yield next(iterator)
                except StopIteration:
                    iHasItems[n] = False
```

Comment: Refactoring questions are rather broad; this question would be a better fit for Codereview (given that it is your own code and that it works). See https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Oh. Did not even know that SE existed. Thanks.

Comment: Look at the `roundrobin` function in the "recipes" section of the [documentation for itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes). I believe it does what you want, is pythonic, and avoids that array of flags.

Comment: And Rory already found it, but you are basically re-implementing the `roundrobin()` function documented in the itertools documentation [recipes section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes); it cycles through iterators and slicing off the last one each time a `StopIteration` exception is raised; that last iterator is always the one that just got exhausted.

Comment: Boy do I feel dumb now. I thought I had googled for it well enough... It did feel weird that nobody had implemented such a basic thing.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically re-implementing the `roundrobin()` function documented in the itertools documentation [recipes section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    num_active = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
    while num_active:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            # Remove the iterator we just exhausted from the cycle.
            num_active -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, num_active))
```

This cycles through iterators and slicing off the last one each time a `StopIteration` exception is raised; that last iterator is always the one that just got exhausted.

Specifically, for the input example, `nexts` starts as a circular list of `<iter('ABC'), iter('D'), iter('EF')>`, in those positions, and `num_active` is `3`, after which the algorithm then progresses through:

1. yielding `A` and leaving `<iter('D'), iter('EF'), iter('BC')>`
2. yielding `D` and leaving `<iter('EF'), iter('BC'), <iter('')>`
3. yielding `E` and leaving `<iter('BC'), <iter(''), iter('F')>`
4. yielding `B` and leaving `<iter(''), iter('F'), iter('C')>`
5. trying to yield but hitting a `StopIteration` exception; the cycle is then at `<iter('F'), iter('C'), iter(*stopped*)>`, so `num_active` becomes `2`, `cycle(islice(nexts, 2))` sets the cycle to `<iter('F'), iter('C')>` and `while` loop continues to
6. yielding `F` and leaving `<iter('C'), iter('')>`
7. yielding `C` and leaving `<iter(''), iter('')>`

after which the final two empty iterators trigger further `StopIteration` exceptions, and `num_active` goes from 2 to 1 to 0 and the `while` loop ends.

You could implement the same with a `collections.deque()` object, and manual rotation:

```
from collections import deque

def roundrobin(*iterables):
    nexts = deque((iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables))
    while nexts:
        try:
            yield nexts[0]()
            # rotate the queue to the left for the next step
            nexts.rotate(-1)
        except StopIteration:
            # Remove the iterator we just exhausted from the queue
            nexts.popleft()
```

but this approach is slower than the `cycle` variant, as rotation is done 'manually', incurring a cost every iteration, outweighing the simpler 'exhausted' exception case implementation.

Like your approach, this saves you having to repeatedly attempt to iterate over any already-exhausted iterators, and unlike the `zip_longest()` approaches posted by others, doesn't require you to test for a sentinel value (`item is not None` or `not item` or `item is not unique_sentinel_singleton`) each iteration.

Answer (score -1):

You zip the `iterables` and `chain` them together

```
from itertools import chain, zip_longest
def zipper(*many):
    return  filter(None, chain(*zip_longest(*many)))
```

Comment: This will stop whenever any iterator is exhausted.

Comment: What if they're not the same length? I thought `zip` truncated to the length of the shortest

Comment: @RiccardoOrlando. Modified to work with iterators of unequal length

Comment: @Amadan Modified to work with iterators of unequal length

Comment: This would skip any falsy value in the input iterators, such as `0` or `None` or `False` or `''`. At the *very least* use a singleton sentinel value that won't appear in the input iterators to test for the 'padding' value `zip_longest()` inserts. And it's simply not efficient to use this method; what if all but one of the iterators is short, and the long iterator is **very very** long? You can save yourself all those `if item` tests by *eliminating exhausted iterators*.